How to stop OnTriggerEnter function calls when they are too fast [Unity]
When there are a lot of monsters, it seems like TriggerEnter2D gets called multiple times as the player's bullets attack them. I tried to block the call with the code, but it doesn't seem to work. How should I fix it?
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (is_trigger) return; // 이미 처리 중인 충돌이 있으면 반환
    //불값 걸어서 중복 방지
    if (collision.transform.gameObject.layer == 6 && !is_trigger) //"Target"레이어에 해당하는 오브젝트라면
    {
        is_trigger = true; //여기서 막아
        DamageableImp target = collision.GetComponent<DamageableImp>();
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.OnDamage(my_hit_data.OnAttack(collision));
            Debug.Log(name + "공격 나갔습니다."+ collision.name +"이 맞았습니다.");
            ReleaseObject();
            return;
        }
        //이펙트 실행 후
    }
    else if (collision.tag == "Plane" && !is_trigger)
    {
        is_trigger = true;
        Debug.Log(name + "공격 나갔습니다. 바닥이 맞았습니다.");
        ReleaseObject();           
    }
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    if (ObjectPoolManager.instance.IsReady)
    {
        transform.position = init_transform.position;
        StopCoroutine("BulletMove");
        is_trigger = false;

    }
}

public void ReleaseObject()
{
    Pool.Release(this.gameObject);
}

The error occurs in the Release() function. The problem lies in attempting to return an object that has already been returned. It seems that TriggerEnter2D is being called redundantly.

just to confirm: What I understand is, this is attached to a bullet, you fire only one bullet at a time towards multiple enemies, you would expect this to only trigger exactly once - but instead it triggers multiple times on the same bullet. Is that correct? Could you add a bit more context to convert this into a [mcve] .. we don't know how ReleaseObject relates to OnDisable and when the check for ObjectPoolManager.instance.IsReady might not be matching
